# SQL Server 2005 Report Builder 2.0 - TFS Reporting : DATEDIFF between Start and Finish dates of a workitem

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, tfs, report-builder2.0

First of all thank you on advance for taking the time to access my question here.

I'm using Report Builder 2.0 for TFS Reporting with the TFS OLAP Cube as the main datasource.

I need to calculate the time taken between the start and end (completion) of a workitem as filled in in the appopriate TFS form.

When I use the following formula:

> DATEDIFF(DAY; Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate_Date_(Date); Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_EndDate_Date_(Date))

I get the following error when running the report in the browser:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for data set 'dataSet'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Semantic query execution failed. (rsSemanticQueryEngineError)
A grouping expression must be either a scalar field or an entity.
```

I have been around this for days and haven't found an answer anywhere.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a big part of your query, can you post the whole statement?